# How to keep session value in dialog flow with express-session Node.js

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, express-session

I am working on google dialog flow.I want to keep track username and password. I decided to use express-session in Node.js. Session value is working when locally, its not working when using with dialog flow app. How to track the value in session?

Comment: There are several things unclear here. What platform are you using Dialogflow for? What have you tried so far? Can you show code to illustrate what you're doing?

Comment: What is at bot-client side? I mean web-app, FB messenger or something else. In case you are using web-app then you can first authenticate user in web-app and then save the auth token in cookies. Then you can send auth token in every request to DF.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js sessions and HTTP sessions aren't available when you're using a Dialogflow webhook since Dialogflow doesn't act like a browser.

You'll need to store the information you want in a Dialogflow [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts) parameter and then read the values from the parameters back later. Exactly how you do this depends on the library you're using in Dialogflow to send back the reply or if you're doing it with just JSON.

Contexts, however, only last for a limited time (human conversations tend to have short-term reference, with long-term references using other means). If you need to retain user information for longer, then you'll need to store the information in a data store such as a database keyed against the platform-specific user ID.

(It isn't clear why you're prompting the user for a username and password, but these seem like strange things to ask for as part of a conversation agent, and are usually handled before handing the conversation off to Dialogflow.)

Comment: I used context in dialog flow.I used two different intent for getting username and password.I used to access the username and password from context.But context value expires soon.I want to keep the context value for one day.

Comment: Answer clarified, but it seems strange you're using Dialogflow to get the username and password. That is pretty atypical for a conversation agent.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Can you tell me how to get the username and password then proceed based  on authentication

Answer (score -1):

You can use req.session object to store your session. 
Example

```
//username is the name attribute of a textfield in your form
res.session.user = req.body.username;
```

You can refer to this for more info

https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: I used the req.session.user="abc";But its not working with dialog flow app.Session value return undefined always.

Comment: Please post the code , so we can find where the issue is